# Using jQuery.load() with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, jquery, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite to get SEO friendly URLs

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /page.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /page.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L]
```

So I can load http://foo.com/food/local.  Works great but it loads whole page and client would like to add a streaming player that persists across page loads.

So I am trying to switch to loading all content with jQuery.load()

```
<script>
   $(".ajax").click( function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#contentMain').load( $(this).attr("href"), function() {console.log( "Load was performed." ); });
    });         
</script>
```

I can get this to load my whole page into #contentMain but I confused about how to maintain the SEO URLs while loading a stripped version of PHP that only swaps contents.

Eg coming to http://foo.com/food/local would load whole page but clicking a link with href /food/foreign from http://foo.com/food/local does not hit page.php per mod_rewrite but just polls content.php with same args?  Should I reconstruct page.php to recognize context in some way?

Also when using this method do you then update meta-description and title via AJAX?  Or does it not matter as long as http://foo.com/food/local can be spidered and have correct meta-info?

Comment: You should let all your links intact and linking to the pages. Then using jQuery you "catch" the click events of these links and just reload the content (and perhaps use javascript to set the URL in the adress bar). This is the best solution since it also works if a user has no javascript enabled

Comment: In php, detect if the request is an ajax request. If it is, return a stripped-down version, else, return the full version. http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Comment: @KevinB what an excellent resource! That just made my life waaaaay easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an ajax call why not just access the non friend page.php link? It should still be accessible. You could add a data attribute to you href's with the page link:

```
<a href="/food/local/" data-ajax="page.php?page=$1">Local Food</a>
```

Anyway, just a thought.

Comment: That works very well!  Thank you!  What do you think about page meta-info?  Would you update or leave alone since spiders won't navigate by AJAX.

Comment: Great! I wouldn't worry too much about meta... like you say the spiders will only crawl the full pages. Maybe consider changing the page title. U can add another data or title attribute.

Comment: i.e. document.title = $(this).attr("title") - and having title in the A tag is also good for SEO